# goBack() function of webview doesnt work when html string is loaded

Tags: android, html, webview

I am setting a HTML string to a webview. The html string contains hyperlinks(clickable links). when the user clicks on the link, it is loaded in the same webView. When the user presses back, the goBack() function works but doesnt load back the string. I also tried loading the html string again when the user presses back. But this doesnt work. Posting my code below.

```
mDescriptionWebVIew.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mDescriptionWebVIew.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if ((i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mDescriptionWebVIew.canGoBack()) {

                mDescriptionWebVIew.goBack();
                if(urlList.size()!=0) {
                    urlList.remove(urlList.size() - 1);
                }
                if(urlList.size()==0){
                    mDescriptionWebVIew.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlFinal, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
mDescriptionWebVIew.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
mDescriptionWebVIew.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            urlList.add(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using the `baseUrl` parameter (first parameter of the `loadDataWithBaseURL` method), then maybe you just need `loadData` instead:

```
mDescriptionWebVIew.loadData(htmlFinal, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works. But how do I set the height of the webview to its content? Because the link clicked from the webview is lengthier and when he presses back, there is a white space left.

Comment: @SahanaPrabhakar Sounds like you might want a JavascriptInterface on your page that will callback to the WebView and trigger a resize. Look here: https://capdroid.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/resizing-webview-to-match-the-content-size/

Comment: loadData method is not efecient when you need simultanesly two html page load.. it is dont load